# How to access the current running ipynb file's metadata without /content api

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I hava this scenario:
create an empty ipynb file (blank code block) in programming way, but i need insert some key-value into this file's metadata, which is business-required so that i can access the key-value in ipynb file's certain cells.  The key-value i insert is used to  transfer from other context into the ipynb file context.

now i have a solution to achieve the above scenario as followding:
use /content rest api to create the specific ipynb file, in the ipynb file i could use ipynbname lib to get the current running ipynb file (ipynbname.name method)； then use /content rest api to get the metadata info .

this solution depends on a running notebook instance（which support /content rest api）, now i want to know , is there another solution without /content rest api , such as ipynbname python lib ？

thanks all